# GWT:creat a simple meteogram in GWTHighCharts

Tags: gwt, highcharts

i am trying to build a meteogram as [this](http://www.highcharts.com/studies/meteogram.htm)

In this chart there's xaxis below with values like 00,06,12,18
These are fine  but how can i add the above values like   satNov14, sunNov15, MonNov16

as there's multiple Yaxis but no multiple xaxis.

I am trying this , but after that am not getting the above dates in proper order

```
                 final Chart chart = new Chart()  

    .setBorderColor("#C7D5D5")
    .setBorderWidth(3)
    .setBorderRadius(0)
    .setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF")
    .setChartTitleText("Meteogram")  
    .setSpacingTop(5)
    .setChartSubtitleText("yr.no")
    .setColumnPlotOptions(new ColumnPlotOptions()  

    .setDataLabels(new DataLabels()  
    .setEnabled(true)  
    ) )


    .setToolTip(new ToolTip() 
    .setFormatter(new ToolTipFormatter() {  
        public String format(ToolTipData toolTipData) {  
            String s; 

            if (toolTipData.getPointName() != null) { 
                s = toolTipData.getPointName() + ": " +  
                toolTipData.getYAsLong() + " ,";  
            } else {  
                s = toolTipData.getXAsString() + ": " +  
                toolTipData.getYAsLong();  
            }  
            return s;  

        }  
    })  
    )  
    .setLabelItems(  
            new LabelItem()  
            .setHtml("")  
            .setStyle(new Style()  
            .setLeft("40px")  
            .setTop("8px")  
            .setColor("black")  
            )  
    );  

    // Primary yAxis  
    chart.getYAxis(0).setGridLineWidth(1).setAxisTitleText("test")
    .setAxisTitle(new AxisTitle()  
    .setText("") 

    )  
    .setLabels(new YAxisLabels()  
    ////                .setStyle(new Style()  
    ////                    .setColor("#89A54E")  
    //                )  
    .setFormatter(new AxisLabelsFormatter() {  
        public String format(AxisLabelsData axisLabelsData) {  
            return axisLabelsData.getValueAsLong() + "Â°";  
        }  
    })  
    );  

    // Secondary yAxis  
    chart.getYAxis(1).setGridLineWidth(2)  
    .setAxisTitle(new AxisTitle()  
    .setText("")  
    )  
    .setOpposite(true)  
    .setLabels(new YAxisLabels()  
    .setFormatter(new AxisLabelsFormatter() {  
        public String format(AxisLabelsData axisLabelsData) {  
            return  axisLabelsData.getValueAsLong() + "Â°";  
        }  
    })  
    );
    Point p1 = new Point(5, 5);
    Marker m = new Marker();
    m.setEnabled(true);
    m.setOption("symbol", "url(41.png)");
    p1.setMarker(m);

    Point p2 = new Point(4.5, 4.5);
    p2.setMarker(m);

    Point p3 = new Point(4, 4);
    Marker m1 = new Marker();
    m1.setEnabled(true);
    m1.setOption("symbol", "url(41.png)");
    p3.setMarker(m1);



    chart.getXAxis(1).setGridLineWidth(1).setLinkedTo(0)

    .setOpposite(true) 


    .setCategories("Sat Nov13", "Sat Nov14", "Sat Nov15", "Sat Nov16"); 

    chart.getXAxis(0).setGridLineWidth(1)
    .setCategories("18","00","06","12","18","00","06","12","18","00","06","12","18","00","06","12","18") ;



    chart.addSeries(chart.createSeries()
            .setName("")  

            .setType(Series.Type.COLUMN)
            .setPlotOptions(new ColumnPlotOptions()  
            .setColor("#24CBE5"))

            .setPoints(new Number[]{  
                    0,0,0,3,5,3,0,1,3,1,0,0,0,0}
            )  
            .setYAxis(1) 
    );

    chart.addSeries(chart.createSeries()  
            .setName("")  
            .setType(Series.Type.SPLINE)
            .setPoints(new Number[]{  
                    5,4.5,4,5,1,0,0,0,3,5,6,3,7,2 })
                    .setPlotOptions(new ColumnPlotOptions() 
                    .setMarker(m1)

                    .setColor("#4572A7"))

    ); 
    return chart;  
}
```

Attached is my output[image]

Any Suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Did you even look how the example chart is implemented? It's pretty clear it has multiple x-axis too, with one of them with an attribute  `opposite: true`.

Comment: i already tried opposite , but its not working properly , i am definitely doing it in a wrong way, but thats what i was looking for ,is the example implementation is provided? if so kindly provide the link , also i edited my question .

Comment: The implementation is in the source of the page. It's a web page after all. Right click, View Source. The implementation is in the `<script>` block inside the `<head>` tag.

Comment: thanks, we do have the source option but not for metegoram , can u see the page where i can find the Metegoram code .. thanks

Comment: Sorry you are correct. I'll post a solution when I have some time later tonight if no one has done so by then.

Comment: @DTing,  Thanks , i'll be looking forward for your solution

Comment: Actually xAxis is of type date/time , but i dont know how to do it and how to put dates,like today's date and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Strelok said, the code is in the `<script>` tag if you right click the page and view source.

```
xAxis: [
{ 
  type: 'datetime',
  tickInterval: 6 * 3600 * 1000,
  tickPosition: 'inside',
  tickLength: 30,
  gridLineWidth: 1,
  gridLineColor: '#F0F0F0',
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false,
  minPadding: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  offset: 30,
  showLastLabel: true,
  labels: {
    formatter: function(){
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H', this.value);
    }
  }
}, 
{ 
  linkedTo: 0,
  tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
  labels: {
  formatter: function(){
    return Highcharts.dateFormat(
      '<span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">%a</span>, %b %e', this.value);
    },
    align: 'left',
    x: 3
  },
  opposite: true,
  tickLength: 20,
  gridLineWidth: 1
}],
```

Top part is for bottom labels, bottom part is for top labels from the looks of it.

edit:

Give this a shot.

```
chart.getXAxis(1)
    .setLinkedTo(0)
    .setGridLineWidth(1)
    .setOpposite(true) 
    .setTickInterval(24 * 3600 * 1000) // 24 hour tick intervals
    .setCategories("Sat Nov13", "Sat Nov14", "Sat Nov15", "Sat Nov16"); 

chart.getXAxis(0)
    .setGridLineWidth(1)
    .setCategories("18","00","06","12","18","00","06","12","18","00","06","12","18","00","06","12","18");
    .setTickInterval(6 * 3600 * 1000) // 6 hour tick intervals
    .setTickPosition("inside")
    .setStartOnTick(false)
    .setEndOnTick(false)
    .setOffset(30)
    .setShowLastLabel(true)
```

Comment: thanks , actually i was searching for Java code ( as i am building it in GWT(highcharts), if u know the java code for GWT for this metegoram ,i'll be greatful

Comment: its org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. Is the axis added to the chart before it is drawn or is chart getting redrawn after you modify the axis? Can you post some more of your code?

Comment: i just edited my question with complete code and the output i am getting  , thanks

Comment: It looks like both X Axis are on the graph as you specified. Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: actually it should be like  satNov13 should contain the four fields below i.e 18,00,06,12 . sunNov14 should contain the next four fields and so on, kindly review the link i added in my Question above(actual metegoram example) ,it should be like that, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in case you use unix epoch timestamps for your dates and if you need it the timestamp to be displayed in date format - just set the type of the axis to datetime

for example:
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
        }
      });

check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HnwbQ/1/

reference: http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--type

Comment: i just want the dates to display at the top  and other values like  00,06,12,18 at the bottom , just c the link in my question , its using multiple x axis , how can i achieve multiple x axis